# Parsing Get-Counter data to just get the values

Tags: parsing, powershell, powershell-2.0

I would like to get the total number of bytes that my computer has sent/received over some interval.

Powershell has a handy cmdlet that gets me access to that information (Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter is the name of my interface):

`Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter)\Bytes received/sec" -Continuous`

It gets the data just fine, but it comes out like this:

[image]

The closes I could get to having it come out the way I wanted was using `Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter)\Bytes received/sec" -Continuous | Format-Table -Property Readings` but that still had a long path name in front of the value I want.

Additionally, if I try setting the output to be some variable, no assignment ever gets done (variable stays null).

How can I get this data in a decent format?

**Note:** The goal is to keep a running tally of this information, and then do something when it reaches a threshold. I can do that if I can get the above to work, but if there is a better way to do it, I am more than happy to use that instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Pipe to `Foreach-Object` and get the value from the CounterSamples property. CounterSamples is an array and the value is in the first item:

```
Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter)\Bytes received/sec" -Continuous |
Foreach-Object {$_.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue}
```

Comment: And is there a way to store these values?

Comment: sure, just assign it to a variable.

Comment: `$test = Get-Counter -Counter "\Network Interface(Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter)\Bytes received/sec" -Continuous |
Foreach-Object {$_.CounterSamples.CookedValue[0]}` Leaves test as null

Comment: I'm tesing on v3 and it works but I may have wrote it in the wrong order, try this instead: $_.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue if it works I'll update the thread.

Comment: As an aside, how can I get V3 on windows 8?

Comment: v3 is shipped with Windows 8. So, this is not working for you: $_.CounterSamples[0].CookedValue ?

Comment: What happens if you remove the Continuous switch? It makes sense that the assignment will not work as expected because the Continuous switch makes it run forever and you have to press ctrl+c to abort execution.

Comment: If I remove the switch then it works, but I want that switch. Seems the easy way to do it is just to get the value from inside the foreach